# Tie several elements to the same function jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using [Alphanum](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum) to restrict character entries on a form.

I have a bunch of elements that all need to use the same set of rules, but they are named differently. Instead of defining them all individually :

```
$("#e1").numeric({
  allowMinus   : false,
  allowThouSep : false,
  allowDecSep : false,
  maxDigits : 1
});

$("#e2").numeric({
  allowMinus   : false,
  allowThouSep : false,
  allowDecSep : false,
  maxDigits : 1
});

....
```

Can I bind them all to one call of `numeric`?

I've tried the following but it didn't work :

```
$("#e1"), ("#e2"), ("#e3").numeric({
  allowMinus   : false,
  allowThouSep : false,
  allowDecSep : false,
  maxDigits : 1
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them all in the same selector:

```
$("#e1, #e2, #e3").numeric(...);
```

You could also give all the elements a common class, then use a class selector.

Comment: Absolute legend. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you ;)